# cloudflare SSH and sockets: how to run them together?

Tags: sockets, socket.io, cloudflare

I am using a **flexible SSL from cloudflare**, so my site is now

**https**://www.example.com

Inside my site, I use socket.io :

```
server = 'http://direct.example.com';
socket = io.connect(server+":1445" , {'force new connection': true });
```

Problem is I got:

```
    Mixed Content: The page at 'https://' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 
'http://direct.example.com:1445/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1434191759199-17'.
```

So how can I keep the https on my site and call sockets from my server ?

(my server does not have any SSL: I use flexible SSL from cloudflare)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudFlare can't proxy websockets right now for anyone other than an Enterprise customer (we're rolling out broader support later this year). Unless it is going over one of these [ports we support](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-CloudFlare-work-with-)right now, then it needs to be on a subdomain we don't touch (this would also mean the SSL wouldn't work).

Comment: You mean: if my nodejs socket.io uses one of these ports
 443
2053
2083
2087
2096
8443

It would work ?

Comment: Not gonna say for sure if it would (there are other issues at play). We have a pretty good explanation about the challenges of supporting Websockets on our blog. See: https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-now-supports-websockets/